# Setting up visualstudio to work with an existing org and sandbox?

Tags: developer-console, ide, force.com-ide

I've always worked on the web console. I recently moved to visual studio but I'm having trouble setting up the system.

In short, I'm experiencing information overload and I'm wondering if anyone knows of any simple guides to get me started? Like REALLY simple because the official docs linked to from the VS code page are really overwhelming.

I've manage to set up the CLI, as mentioned in [VS code SF extension doc page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) but have had trouble with "create a Salesforce DX project". I already work on an existing org which has a production and a sandbox if that helps?

Comment: Have you already looked at [this video from 2017 Dreamforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXST9yOyQLk) or other Dreamforce videos on Youtube?

Comment: I had not! I"ll have to check it out

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create an SFDX project, but you're not working in an SFDX environment. The CLI is geared towards SFDX, which doesn't seem to be your case.

I am not sure if the CLI supports traditional development. I would recommend downloading "ForceCode" (You can get to it from the "plugins" menu). It is much more straightforward and it is definitely compatible with non-SFDX projects.

Comment: What's the difference between the two? The impression I got was that SFDX is just a style of doing the development? 

What makes something an SFDX env vs a traditional one?

Comment: That is a VERY long answer. To put it very short, SFDX development is based on a "Development Hub"/"Scratch Org" strategy, where you would create a single-purpose "Scratch Org" from the "Development Hub" for a given task/story and then destroy it once you're done. The source of truth would be source control (git) instead of the code in the sandbox, as it is during traditional development. I really encourage you to do SFDX trailheads to get more information.